# Why won't this query run via php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have:

```
$con = mysql_connect($db_server,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db($db_db, $con);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO failed_logins SET username = 'pachonk', ip_address = INET_ATON('$ip'), attempted = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
 // mysql_close($con);
echo $ip;

$count = get_attempts(); // Get the Number of Attempts
mysql_close($con);
sleep((2 ^ intval($count)) - 1);

function get_attempts(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM failed_logins WHERE ip_address = INET_ATON('$ip')");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $num_rows;
    }
    else
    {
    echo NO;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And when I run the second query on my SQL server, it runs just how I want it to, however I get 0 lines when I query via php. If I query for "username = pachonk", It's perfect how I want though as well. What's going on?

Comment: insert query is not written like this. This is not update query it is insert which is written in a different way

Comment: you are mixing update and select.

Comment: Insert query is working fine, my select is not.

Comment: How can you say insert query is working fine. It is not inserting anything

Comment: Yes it is, but what I need to fix is the SELECT.

Comment: INET_ATON function gave some number for a IP-Address. If you have saved some ip address instead of that number in DB ? Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

If $ip is not empty(in your example $ip is empty) you can try to modify your function get_attempts() in get_attempts($ip);

Answer (score 0):

your insert query should more or less look like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO failed_logins values('pachonk', INET_ATON('$ip'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
```

then your select will give you some result

Comment: MySQL also support INSERT INTO .. SET statements .